# Mysql order by same items from table

Tags: mysql

I have a db table with stored interests of users:

```
CREATE TABLE `ade39_findme_settings_words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `word` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `clickeditem` (`user_id`),
  KEY `count` (`word`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Where word=interest

Now I want to search in this table for users having one or many same interests AND order this list by the amount of same interests. Any idea how the sql query would look like?

like "all users with similar interest as user_id=62"

**Example:**

```
 USER  INTEREST
 62    riding
 62    reading
 62    dancing
 75    riding
 75    dancing
 80    riding
```

OUTPUT:

```
 USER  SAME_COUNT 
  75   2
  80   1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Same interest as ???

Comment: like "all users with similar interest as user_id=62"

Answer (score 1):

you may run into performance issues so one way you can try and improve that is by using EXISTS

```
SELECT t.user_id, COUNT(*) as num_interests, GROUP_CONCAT(word) as interests
FROM ade39_findme_settings_words t
WHERE EXISTS
(   SELECT 1
    FROM ade39_findme_settings_words t1
    WHERE t1.user_id = 62
      AND t1.word = t.word
)
AND user_id <> 62
GROUP BY t.user_id
ORDER BY num_interests DESC;
```

the fastest way to do this is with an exclusion JOIN though like so

```
SELECT t.user_id, COUNT(*) as num_interests, GROUP_CONCAT(t.word) as interests
FROM ade39_findme_settings_words t
LEFT JOIN ade39_findme_settings_words t1 ON t1.user_id = 62 AND t1.word = t.word
WHERE t.user_id <> 62
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY num_interests DESC;
```

Comment: `SELECT 1` means return the value of the first field, yes?  Or is it the value 1?

Comment: @wallyk no it will just select 1... I could put anything in there it just means is there a matching value or not

Comment: @user2881954 if this solves your issue it would be greatly appreciated if you accepted the answer :) (the checkmark next to my asnwer)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `user_id`, COUNT(*) as same_count
FROM `ade39_findme_settings_words`
WHERE `word` IN (SELECT `word` FROM `ade39_findme_settings_words` WHERE `user_id` = 62)
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY same_count DESC;
```

Comment: well quite close but i get here:

userid | count

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me :

```
select temp.id_new , count(temp.intrst) 
from 
(select a.user_id id_new, a.word intrst 
from   ade39_findme_settings_words a 
where a.word in (select b.word  from ade39_findme_settings_words b where b.user_id=62) 
and a.user_id<>62 ) temp
group by temp.id_new;
```